gSOAP SOAP_LENGTH error occurs regardless of setting both soap.maxlength and soap.recv_maxlength to 0
I have two different types of clients, one using soapC and the other using a Proxy.  Both of them return SOAP_LENGTH whenever the response exceeds a certain threshold (which appears to be 32K or less).  The only places I've found in stdsoap2.cpp where SOAP_LENGTH is returned are those where soap->maxlength is greater than 0 and is exceeded, but explicitly setting it to 0 doesn't resolve the issue.
In addition, the server will often exit with code 141 after one or more such attempts.
SoapUI never experiences this issue, regardless of responses exceeding even 64K.
Version is 2.8.52

Max length checks are not only enforced by the value set for the general soap->maxlength, but are also enforced based on constraints specified in the XML schema translated to C or C++. For example, a string member of a class may have a lower an upper bound length. When content exceeds these limits then an error is reported by the parser/validator.
